# Python websocket подключение как клиент , обмен сообщениями

Tags: python, websocket, асинхронность

Я хочу подключить стрим wss на сайте investing . При подключении я получаю в ответе "o" , что говорит мне о том , что подключение успешно , далее мне нужно отправить 3 сообщения как на скриншоте [image: скрин]

после получать ответ и переодически отправлять "{"_event":"heartbeat","data":"h"}"
но у меня возникают проблемы , сообщения видимо не отправляються .
Очень сильно нужна помощь в решении данной проблемы , вот мой код :

```
import asyncio
import websockets


uri = "wss://stream100.forexpros.com/echo/039/vd9f1u3h/websocket" # url вебсокета


one = "{\"_event\":\"bulk-subscribe\",\"tzID\":8,\"message\":\"pid-1057391:%%pid-1061443:%%pid-1061453:%%pid-1061448:%%pid-1114630:%%pid-169:%%pid-166:%%pid-172:%%pid-24441:%%pid-178:%%pid-171:%%pid-14958:%%pid-8830:%%pid-8849:%%pid-1:%%pid-13994:%%pid-23705:%%pid-8874:%%pid-8873:%%pid-2:%%pid-3:%%pid-7:%%pid-5:%%pid-4:%%pid-8839:%%pid-20:%%pid-27:%%pid-179:%%pid-1175152:%%pid-1175153:%%pid-44336:%%pid-8827:%%pid-8833:%%pid-945629:%%event-448131:%%event-448132:%%event-448141:%%event-448128:%%event-448136:%%event-448129:%%event-448139:%%isOpenExch-1:%%isOpenExch-2:%%isOpenPair-1175152:%%isOpenPair-1175153:%%isOpenPair-44336:%%isOpenPair-8827:%%domain-1:\"}"
two = "{\"_event\":\"UID\",\"UID\":234473696}"
tre = "{\"_event\":\"heartbeat\",\"data\":\"h\"}"

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:

        await ws.recv()

        await ws.send(one)
        await ws.send(two)
        await ws.send(tre)
        while True:

            msg = await ws.recv()
            print(msg)



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

ошибки которрые я получаю asyncio.exceptions.IncompleteReadError: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes и websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в метод `send` добавить `\n`.

```
await ws.send(one + "\n")
await ws.send(two + "\n")
await ws.send(tre + "\n")
```

Чтобы указать, где конец строки. В некоторых сокетах это не предусмотренно, поэтому может помочь.

Comment: к сожалению это не помогло